# Modelado de tablas en MySQL: ¿centralizar todos los datos de las personas en una sola tabla o las separarla por entidad?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy construyendo una REST API con Spring Boot pero mi duda viene por el modelado de la base de datos. La duda es la siguiente: ¿centralizo todos los datos de las personas en una sola tabla o las separo por cada entidad?
Ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE personas (
  id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  dni VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  nombre VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
  apellido VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
  sexo TINYINT(1) COMMENT 'False = hombre\ntrue = mujer',
  direccion VARCHAR(150),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE clientes (
  id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  persona_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_clientes_personas` FOREIGN KEY (`persona_id`) REFERENCES `personas` (`id`)
)
```

Este seria el caso para un cliente (faltan mas datos como estado, datos de factura, etc) pero existen más entidades como instructores, empleados, usuarios entonces por eso mi duda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la teoría de la [programación orientada a objetos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_orientada_a_objetos) (véase el concepto de Herencia), en la entidad `persona` deberías colocar **únicamente los campos inherentes a todas las personas**, y en las entidades heredadas (instructor, cliente, etc.), solamente los **campos específicos**.

Ahora bien, si podrías centralizar todo en `persona`, pero estarías yendo en contra del sexenio del paradigma POO. Funcionaría, pero estarías haciendo un sistema de calidad inferior. Sería más difícil de mantener. Supón que necesitas agregar otro 'tipo de persona': deberías modificar la clase madre completa, y sería más propenso a errores.

Comment: Leyendo nuevamente mi consulta me he dado cuenta que me exprese mal, mi duda en el modelado es: utilizo una tabla donde se agrupen todos los atributos en común de cualquier persona (dni, nombre, apellido, correo, etc.) o para cada entidad cliente, instructor, usuario, etc. especificar ahí los atributos. Como los datos básicos se iran repitiendo en las diferentes tablas, mi duda es centrar esos datos en una única tabla e ir relacionandola con las demás, como ejemplo el código DML de la publicación, o ir entidad por entidad definiendo esos atributos (nombre, apellido, etc.).

Comment: Sería la primer opción. La idea es que no repitas esos campos en todas las tablas. Es precisamente la idea de la herencia. Imagina que necesitas agregar un campo más para todas las personas (digamos... grupo sanguíneo), tendrías que modificar todas las tablas hijas para agregar el campo grupo sanguíneo. No solo lo complica más, sino que es propenso a errores, podrías olvidar agregar el campo en una entidad, podrías tener ese campo en una tabla como VARCHAR(5) y en otra como VARCHAR(10). Es susceptible a inconsistencias. Como te dije, igual funciona, pero no es el diseño más óptimo y eficiente.

Comment: Y ni hablar si tuvieras que hacer una estadística de los grupos sanguíneos de todas las personas de tu B.D., te volverías loco.

Answer (score 0):

Siendo poco academico, si no usas claves foraneas para representar la herencia entre persona y cliente/usuario/instructor etc, y usas solo una tabla, vas a tener muchos campos en Null, ya que un cliente no tiene el campo idInstituto que tiene instructor, ni el campo idPerfil que tiene usuario, por eso tenes que hacer diferentes tablas.

Comment: Leyendo nuevamente mi consulta me he dado cuenta que me exprese mal, mi duda en el modelado es: utilizo una tabla donde se agrupen todos los atributos en común de cualquier persona (dni, nombre, apellido, correo, etc.) o para cada entidad cliente, instructor, usuario, etc. especificar ahí los atributos. Como los datos básicos se iran repitiendo en las diferentes tablas, mi duda es centrar esos datos en una única tabla e ir relacionandola con las demás, como ejemplo el código DML de la publicación, o ir entidad por entidad definiendo esos atributos (nombre, apellido, etc.).

Comment: Deberías crear una tabla con los campos en común, nombre apellido etc, y una tabla con los campos de cada entidad, usuario, pass, por ejemplo en usuario.
Luego relacionar estas con una clave foránea, se supongo que seria IdPersona.